# Changing the SQL sorting query in Primefaces

Tags: api, sorting, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 2.2.1. Its datatable supports sorting well. I see that when I click in each column heading and sorting performs, there's a request to server and execute an SQL query to reload the datatable again with the new order. 
But I want to sort and group all records in my own way. How can I do this ? Does Primefaces have an API for this purpose ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is the link to download PrimeFaces v2.2.1's [documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_2_2.pdf). They documented quite clearly about each and every component. You should get most of what you need from it.

Comment: I've found the solution. That documentation isn't enough. The better one is the API doc in the compressed file on Google code [primefaces 2.2.1.zip](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/downloads/detail?name=primefaces-2.2.1.zip&can=2&q=) What I've done is overriding LazyDataModel of Primefaces.

Comment: Well, I did said you will get "most" of what you need :P. Anyway, to provide your own sort function, the answer from Daniel is enough and it's actually documented. Besides, it seems that you are using `@RequestScoped`?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to sort in your own way do the following

```
<p:column sortBy="#{car.model}" sortFunction="#{carBean.sortByModel}">
```

and in your bean implement the following :

```
public int sortByModel(Car car1, Car car2) {
    //return -1, 0 , 1 if car1 is less than, equal to or greater than car2
}
```

and b.t.w no SQL query needed to be done upon sort , just populate the List once in your bean and that's it , sound like your getter(or entire bean) is written wrongly